# How To Store exec and render it to a template in Django?

Tags: python, html, django

I am creating a website where I can store my code. I also want a feature where I can run the code! So I used exec, but I can't render it to a html page. It justs prints the output to the console.

This is my views.py

```py
def SeeCode(request, code_pk):
    code = Code.objects.get(pk=code_pk)
    execute = exec(code)
    context = {
        "code": code,
        "execute": execute
    }
    return render(request, "base/see_code.html", context)
```

And this is my html page:

```html
{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ code.title }}</h1>
    <br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md-7" id="col1">
            <pre><code class="python">{{code.code}}</code></pre>
            <br>
            <a class="run">Execute</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col md-4" id="col2">
            <h6>OUTPUT</h6>
            <p>{{ execute }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    

{% endblock %}
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this?
Or any alternative ways to run the python code and render it to my html page?

Comment: Although your application needs to execute user code, still running that _directly_ on your server is **dangerous**. You should be using some sandbox and executing the code there (not on your webserver)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You should be researching on running / sandboxing untrusted code instead of trying `exec` or any other thing. A few links that might get you started https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191623/best-practices-for-execution-of-untrusted-code https://superuser.com/questions/690553/run-user-code-safely https://dev.to/narasimha1997/building-a-secure-sandboxed-environment-for-executing-untrusted-code-7e8

Comment: Ok thank you! I will take a look at the links!